# Cannot convert value of type 'UITableViewCell' to specified type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have just created a new custom cell in the file 'Celda', now I need to use the labels in my UITableView using JSON.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : Celda = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("jsonCell")!
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.nombre1.text = dict["nombre"] as? String
    cell.nombre2.text = dict["calle"] as? String
    cell.id.text = dict["id"] as? String
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrRes.count
}
```

But I am getting error in 'let' line. It says: `Cannot convert value of type 'UITableViewCell' to specified type 'Celda'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("jsonCell") as! Celda
```

Comment: only if _Celda_ is your`UITableViewCell` custom class

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableView {
        let cell : CustomCell = tblv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row] 
        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.breedName.text = breeds[indexPath.row] as String

   return cell     
 }
```